# React router params and querys is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

From last couple of days i was finding a solution for this problem.what is happening here is i want dynamic link.you can see below here:

```
<Route path="/edit/:username" component={EditExpensePage} />
```

But when I go to `/edit/12`, I'm getting this error:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/edit/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import ExpenseDashboardPage from '../components/ExpenseDashboardPage';
import AddExpensePage from '../components/AddExpensePage';
import EditExpensePage from '../components/EditExpensePage';
import HelpPage from '../components/HelpPage';
import NotFoundPage from '../components/NotFoundPage';
import Header from '../components/Header';

const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Header />

        <Route path="/" component={ExpenseDashboardPage} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/create" component={AddExpensePage} />
        <Route path="/edit/:username" component={EditExpensePage} />
        <Route path="/help" component={HelpPage} />

    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: It seems like your server is handling the requests rather than `react-router`. Make your server return the `index.html` for every routes. That's usually a `.*` regex at the server level. You didn't share anything about where you're hosting your page so I can't be more specific.

Comment: First of all Thank you for answering my question.i  am not hosting anywhere i am using localhost or you can say i am using 127.0.0.1.i already install path-to-regexp dependencies but then also it is not working.sorry for bad English and please ignore my spelling mistakes.thank you

Comment: i am facing the same problem but i dit not get any solution from your answer.. please elaborate your answer that i can understand the exact solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're loading your `bundle.js` file with a relative URL.

So when you load the page `http://127.0.0.1/Home` (or whatever) it resolves as `http://127.0.0.1/bundle.js`, which is correct.

However when you load the page `http://127.0.0.1/edit/12` it resolves as `http://127.0.0.1/edit/bundle.js`, which is incorrect.

Make the `<script` tag use an absolute URL.

Comment: Thank you after 2 times restarting dev-server finally it's working.thank you

Comment: i am facing the same problem but i dit not get any solution from your answer.. please elaborate your answer that i can understand the exact solution. @Drew Noakes